# bin/sh: 1: arm-eabi-gcc not found

Tags: cross-compiling, sh, bin

I'm trying to compile a linux kernel by cross compile method. After solving a lot of problems, i have this one:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/oc2/prebuilt/linux-86X/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: not found
```

Comment: Please, add more information on the command you're trying to run.

Comment: make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<tool-chain-path>/bin/arm-android-eabi- uImage

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?bwmn1v1a1lwbq9r

Comment: I am should add a useful note, that I just tried compile a helloworld with two different gcc compilers, and for one of them the sh gave me exactly this weird error -- `not found`.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you did not add the correct path to the tool chain properly.

**export PATH=$(pwd)/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin:$PATH**

put this in your AOSP(the folder where you have your android platform in).

Answer (score 0):

because the default gcc/g++ are configured as arm-eabi-gcc by accident perhaps with the command `update-alternatives`. to fix require to revert back alternatives to the original:

`sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++`

next, configure default gcc/g++ for the default host toolchain:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 60`

only then make default arm-eabi-gcc/arm-eabi-g++ available:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/arm-eabi-gcc arm-eabi-gcc /home/oc2/prebuilt/linux-86X/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc 60
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/arm-eabi-g++ arm-eabi-g++ /home/oc2/prebuilt/linux-86X/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-g++ 60`